# merge non matching arrays of objects with ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Im trying to merge two arrays of objects based on position with Ramda. Consider that I have the arrays as follows:

```
const getKeys = [{"name": "id"}, {"name": "temperature"}, {"name": "humidity"}, {"name": "voltage"}, {"name": "upload_time"}]
const getValues = [{data: [1,1,1,1]},{data: [1,2,3,4]},{data: [5,6,7,8]},{data: [1,2,3,4]},{data: [1,2,3,4]}]
```

I want to end up with:

```
[{"name": "id", data: [1,1,1,1]}, {"name": "id", data: [1,2,3,4]}, etc...]
```

So far i have tried it with `R.mergeWith` but this only merges on matching keys.

Comment: What about javascript's `map()` ?

Answer (score 2):

[`zip`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zip) and its cousin [`zipWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith) are designed for working with arrays that have paired indices.  `zip` would just wrap an array around the two values.  `zipWith` accepts a function and then calls that function with each pair.  So, using [`merge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#merge), we can write this as `zipWith (merge)`:

```js
const getKeys = [{"name": "id"}, {"name": "temperature"}, {"name": "humidity"}, {"name": "voltage"}, {"name": "upload_time"}]
const getValues = [{data: [1,1,1,1]},{data: [1,2,3,4]},{data: [5,6,7,8]},{data: [1,2,3,4]},{data: [1,2,3,4]}]

console .log (zipWith (merge) (getKeys, getValues))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {zipWith, merge} = R                                  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mergedObject = getKeys.map((keys, index) => ({
   ...keys,
   data: [...getValues[index].data],
}))
```

this will add the valued to the keys object

Comment: I just modified it to not mutate the original

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to replace `data: [...getValues[index].data]` with `...getValues[index]`.  This would use *all* the fields of both, except where their keys overlap.

Comment: But that will still hold a reference to the array inside the values data object

Comment: Something similar would be true in the original if the elements in `getValues[index].data` were not primitives.  If you want to avoid any shared references, you're going to need a deep clone.  I don't find that necessary here, but it's possible the OP would.

Comment: My point was how the technique extends if there are additional fields in the members of `getValues`.  If they were fixed, you could add them one-by-one in your technique.  My suggestion handles all of them at once.